# Finding a Dialog from a context using TestBench

Tags: vaadin, test-bench, vaadin-testbench

I'm looking for a way to find a `DialogElement` from a child context. Finding it from the "root" context is working fine, but I'm building a Page component for testing and when I try to find the `DialogElement` using the `$(DialogElement.class)` approach it tries to find it in the context of the current Element, but Dialog seems to be added to the main/root context, hence it always fails. Any suggestion how to do it?

**UPDATE**

I found a solution that works from anywhere in the test:

```
DialogElement dialogElement = new ElementQuery<>(DialogElement.class).context(getDriver()).first()
```

**UPDATE 2**

Managed to improve it:

```
DialogElement dialogElement = $(DialogElement.class).context(getDriver()).first()
```

If anyone knows a more elegant one feel free to post it.

Comment: Why do you put finding the Dialog to the page object? Simply use $(DialogElement) in your tests. We added a method to get the current dialog to the base class of our UI tests

Comment: Because it logically belongs to that page object and I don't want to break the otherwise encapsulated test sequence just to interact with the Dialog.

Comment: The dialog is always on top so you will no have a chance to do that.

Comment: I don't see why it shouldn't be possible though

Comment: You wrote: "it tries to find it in the context of the current Element" That's why

Comment: I understand why it is not working. I'm looking for a solution and I'm saying that this should be possible technically.

Comment: Selenium (which TestBench is based on) doesn't know anything about logical relationships, it only cares about what the actual DOM tree says. `$(DialogElement.class).first()` should do the trick if you only have one Dialog, otherwise you can use e.g. `.id` to get a specific one.

Comment: As I explained in my question this only works if you call it from the test case directly (which uses the root context) and doesn't work from within a "page object" as it uses the page object's context and dialog is being added at the top level.

Answer (score 0):

Try DialogElement dialogElement = $(DialogElement.class).onPage().first()

onPage() defines that the query should start the search from the root of the page, in practice from the  tag.